# The import org.osgi cannot be resolved OSGI

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, osgi

I created plugin project with only `Activator` class.

```
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
```

But I get this error: `The import org.osgi cannot be resolved.`

I downloaded the "Equinox OSGi R4 framework implementation" from [Equinox Release Build: Neon.2](http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/drops/R-Neon.2-201611241400/index.php)

Did copy/paste in ProgramFiles\eclipse\plugins and when I search the bundle in OSGi framework configuration it seems like it isn't there [image]

Clicking on "Add Required Bundles" doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score -2):

I solved the problem finally!

Window>Preferences>Plug-in Development>Target Platform should look like this -> [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojjVi.png)

If you don't have this option to select, just click on "Restore Defaults" and it should automaticly appear.